# Why two different versions of sbt in the project

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.6

In my `Play` project I notice that `build.properties` has `sbt` version `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.12")`
 and `build.properties` has `sbt.version=0.13.15`.

1) Why are there two enteries?
2) What is the difference between them
3) Should their versions be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between SBT proper and SBT plugin. Play Framework is an [SBT plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Plugins.html). The [version of SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Basic-Def.html#Specifying+the+sbt+version) is specified in `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.15
```

whilst the [version of Play SBT plugin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/BuildOverview#Play-plugin-for-sbt-(/project/plugins.sbt)) is specified in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.12")
```

Scala Play SBT plugin ([`PlayScala`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/137aa772c3ca38ea553c03e3bdbcdb06af23ea83/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/Play.scala#L87)) is enabled in `build.sbt` like so:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

SBT plugins enrich build definitions with additional useful tasks, commands, settings, and dependencies. Here are some examples from [Play SBT plugin](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/137aa772c3ca38ea553c03e3bdbcdb06af23ea83/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L85):

```
object PlayKeys {
  val playDefaultPort = SettingKey[Int]("playDefaultPort", "The default port that Play runs on")
  val playDefaultAddress = SettingKey[String]("playDefaultAddress", "The default address that Play runs on")
  val playRunHooks = TaskKey[Seq[PlayRunHook]]("playRunHooks", "Hooks to run additional behaviour before/after the run task")
  ...
```

So for example to change the default port that Play runs on we can define in `build.sbt`:

```
PlayKeys.playDefaultPort := 9009
```

Note when upgrading SBT version we need to make sure it is compatible with corresponding Play SBT plugin. [For example](https://blog.playframework.com/play-2-6-6-released/#sbt1support), to use Play with SBT 1 we need to update Play `sbt-plugin` to `2.6.6`.

SBT plugin best practice [artifact naming convention](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#Artifact+naming+convention) encurages the following naming scheme:

```
sbt-$projectname
```

For example, `sbt-scoverage`, `sbt-buildinfo`, `sbt-release`, `sbt-assembly`, however Play named it `sbt-plugin`, which arguably can be confusing.