# Why play is a plugin but not a library dependency for sbt?

Tags: playframework, sbt

While looking at the play project, I found this line in `/project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.0")
```

But I cannot find play in `libraryDependencies ++= ...` in `built.sbt`.

It's quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we could add various Play components directly to `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`, Play's [`sbt-plugin`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/7c196b9d6fc1032cbd75aa729ba55a81d62fcaa3/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala#L60) will take care of that for us by adding

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % play.core.PlayVersion.current % "provided"
```

as well as other relevant dependencies to `libraryDependencies`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52354084/5205022) related answer for more information on Play's SBT plugin. ,